# counting words from a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, twitter

My function is supposed to have:

- One parameter as a tweet.

  - This tweet can involve numbers, words, hashtags, links and punctuations.
- A second parameter is a dictionary that counts the words in that string with tweets, disregarding the hashtag's, mentions, links, and punctuation included in it.

The function returns all individual words in the dictionary as lowercase letters without any punctuation.

If the tweet had `Don't` then the dictionary would count it as `dont`.

Here is my function:

```
    def count_words(tweet, num_words):
''' (str, dict of {str: int}) -> None
Return a NoneType that updates the count of words in the dictionary.

>>> count_words('We have made too much progress', num_words)
>>> num_words
{'we': 1, 'have': 1, 'made': 1, 'too': 1, 'much': 1, 'progress': 1}
>>> count_words("@utmandrew Don't you wish you could vote? #MakeAmericaGreatAgain", num_words)
>>> num_words
{'dont': 1, 'wish': 1, 'you': 2, 'could': 1, 'vote': 1}
>>> count_words('I am fighting for you! #FollowTheMoney', num_words)
>>> num_words
{'i': 1, 'am': 1, 'fighting': 1, 'for': 1, 'you': 1} 
>>> count_words('', num_words)
>>> num_words
{'': 0}
'''
```

Comment: `I am not sure if I am doing this functions correctly`, we aren't sure since we can't see what you've done and tried... Don't just dump what seems like a homework question on us an expect us to write you code for you. We answer specific questions and is more than willing to help someone who has put effort into trying to solve the question.

Comment: Oh sorry what I meant to say was how do I write a proper return statement for this particular function! Or just any tips?

Comment: Read #MooingRawr's comment again. You response is just as empty of usable information and a meaningful question as your original posting. Unless you can ask a good question you cannot get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand your question, but if you want to update the dictionary you can do it in this manner:

```
d = {}
def update_dict(tweet):   
    for i in tweet.split():
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] += 1   
    return d
```